# Why does Microsoft Windows not allow special characters in file and folder names?

Tags: windows, validation

1. I want to know whether it is done to enhance security of the named files? If yes, how? By special characters, I am asking about `'<>"/\`
2. Is there any way to bypass this check?

Comment: 2) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#win32_file_namespaces

Comment: My guess would be it started out a necessity and then became a usability thing. No one wants to see a file named "----___%#@^My Fi13.txt" not to mention how would you distinguish between name characters and the dot for extension or double quotes.

Comment: "If yes, how?" Then what about if no? Then it's off-topic, isn't it?

Comment: @techraf, yes, if it does not have any security implication, then it should be closed.

Comment: Apostrophe `'` is not special and is permitted.

Comment: @one You do know what those characters are for, right? Can you see that it isn't about security but pure functionality?

Answer (score 6):

**1) I want to know whether it is done to enhance security of the named files? If yes, how?**

Well, most of the character restrictions are due to them being reserved to system functions. So I suppose the answer would be **no**.

**Examples**: vertical bar (`|`) is used on Windows to designate software pipelining, less than (`<`) and greater than (`>`) are used to redirect `input` and `output`, respectively, question mark (`?`) is used as a wildcard, etc.

There is a most detailed list of reserved characters on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words) Wikipedia article.

**2) Is there any way to bypass this check?**

Well, yes and no. As far as I know there is no way of using a slash (`/`) in a filename. Period. But, as pointed out by [William Hilsum](https://superuser.com/users/4386/william-hilsum) at [this](https://superuser.com/a/187480) answer, instead of a slash (`/`) one could use a division symbol (`∕`), instead of colon (`:`) one could use the use the modifier letter colon (`꞉`), and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Historically, the restriction is definitely not due to security concerns. It dates back from before security was an objective. Rather it's a restriction of the command line shell: you generally couldn't build a command line that would act on a file whose name contains those special characters, so rather than let people create files that they couldn't manipulate, DOS and then Windows added restrictions in most layers of the OS to prevent all applications from creating such files. DOS forbade spaces; later Windows allows them but left most forbidden punctuation characters as forbidden.

In modern Windows, it's actually possible to access files whose name contains anything but null and backslash using UNC paths (`\\?\…`). This is not supported by all applications.

While security wasn't the objective, experience on Unix shows that it does enhance security. Most Unix systems allow anything except slash and null in file names, but many shell scripts are written carelessly and choke on file names containing shell special characters, especially spaces and wildcards. (See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters), a recurring topic on Unix discussion/support sites, and [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) which focuses on the security aspect.) Windows's native shell language is different so the troublesome special characters aren't the same, but spaces are problematic in both and `"` would be quite problematic in Windows since it's very commonly used to quote file names.

Comment: Plus in Windows globbing and token/wordsplitting are not done by CMD, or earlier by DOS COMMAND, but by each program; for C/etc programs using standard `main` (not `WinMain`) this is usually in the moral equivalent of `crt0.o`. Thus any special handling needed here would be replicated many places -- and experience proves some inconsistency would creep in, causing much confusion and trouble (although as a silver lining, probably lots of easy-answer SX Qs).